# Understanding d3 ball bounce

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I came across the following code that makes a ball bounce. I understand everything except what is happening in the two following lines.  What do the .style transition functions do exactly?

How could I have written this using .each() instead of a `setInterval`? The documentation for `d3` hasn't really clarified it sufficiently to the point where I can fully understand it.

```
 .style("top", bounceBottom)
 .style("top", bounceTop).transition()
```

//full code:

```
var bounceTop = 0 + 'px';
var bounceBottom = (height - radius * 2) + 'px';

var ball = d3.select('.container').selectAll('div')
  .data([0]).enter().append('div').attr('class', 'ball')
  .style({
    top: bounceTop,
    left: width / 2 - radius + 'px',
    width: radius * 2 + 'px',
    height: radius * 2 + 'px'
  });

function bounce() {
  ball.transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .ease("cubic-in")
    .style("top", bounceBottom)

  .transition()
    .ease("cubic-in")
    .duration(1500)
    .style("top", bounceTop).transition()

}

setInterval(function() {
  bounce();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setInterval calls the bounce function every 3 seconds, in those 3 seconds first the ball transition down (animates down) because of the first call to `ball.transition` which takes 1.5 seconds, when this transition ends it calls right away to the second transition moving the ball up which also takes 1.5 seconds and this happens without stopping because of the setInterval

Comment: `.style("top", bounceBottom)` changes the `top` attribute of the element CSS styling. because the element is positioned `absolute` or `relative` you can set for example `top: 50px` and this means it will be 50px from the parent (non static) container. because you use transition If I set `top:50px` and set the transition to `1.5s` it will take the ball in this case to move from `top:0px` to `top:50px` 1.5 seconds.

Comment: OK. in the last .style, why do you need the transition at the end?

Comment: without the transition instead of smoothly animating it would have just jumped to the final location.

Answer (score -1):

To use .each, add `.each('start', bounce)` after your last `.transition()`

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. They are used, the OP wanted to know what they did.